# How to add class dynamically inside a loop using PHP

Tags: php, class

I need one help.I am displaying some data which are coming from DB but i need to set the class name dynamically in each loop iteration using PHP.I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
     $class=array('classname'=>'pic1-caption bottom-to-top','classname'=>'pic1-caption top-to-bottom','classname'=>'pic1-caption left-to-right','classname'=>'pic1-caption right-to-left','classname'=>'pic1-caption rotate-in','classname'=>'pic1-caption rotate-out','classname'=>'pic1-caption open-up','classname'=>'pic1-caption open-down','classname'=>'pic1-caption open-left','classname'=>'pic1-caption open-right','classname'=>'pic1-caption come-left','classname'=>'pic1-caption come-right');
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from phr_health_care where status=1  order by health_id desc");
     $key=0;
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 ?>
<div class="pic1">
 <img src="backend/uploads/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="pic1-image" alt="pic1"/>
 <span class="pic1-caption bottom-to-top"> //here need to set class name dynamically.
 <h1 class="pic1-title">DIABETICS</h1>
 <p class="newp"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></p>
  <a href="health.html" class="detall">Go for Details</a>
</span>
```

Here All data are coming from database and i need to set class name in `span element` dynamically which are declared in `$class` variable .Here also i need once all class declared inside `$class` variable will finish while loop continuing ,again it will start from beginning  until the db value fetch has not finished.Please help me.

Comment: First, you cannot have multiple of the same key in an associative array.

Comment: @FrayneKonok : Here while loop is continuing.In each iteration it will add a new class name which is defined above.if the set of class name will be finish still db value is fetching again class will start from first.

Comment: same key in an associative array is not allowed so please remove it.

Comment: it was my mistake..wrongly i had done this.

Comment: oye...i have not done that..somebody else but your code is working fine.

Comment: i can't figure out, what's going on!!! Is it any competition to win the upvote??
@satya, you have to upvote and accept answer if you are benefited from it.

Comment: @FrayneKonok : i have upvoted and accepted all answers those helped me but i can not understand who is doing like this.

Comment: @satya just for your confirmation, you can mark only one answer but you can up-vote all answer. marking will be happen only for one answer not for all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do some change in your code which are stated by comment itself:-**

**You need to convert your `$class` array into indexed array instead of associative array because all the keys are same and its wrong.**

```
<?php
 $class=array('pic1-caption bottom-to-top','pic1-caption top-to-bottom','pic1-caption left-to-right','pic1-caption right-to-left','pic1-caption rotate-in','pic1-caption rotate-out','pic1-caption open-up','pic1-caption open-down','pic1-caption open-left','pic1-caption open-right','pic1-caption come-left','pic1-caption come-right'); //I make it an indexed array because associative array with same key is wrong and give you error
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from phr_health_care where status=1  order by health_id desc");
 $key=0;// start counter 
 $class_count = count($class); // take count of class array
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 ?>
   <div class="pic1">
   <img src="backend/uploads/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="pic1-image" alt="pic1"/>
   <span class="<?php echo $class[$key];?>"><!--  get classes dynamically-->
     <h1 class="pic1-title">DIABETICS</h1>
     <p class="newp"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></p>
     <a href="health.html" class="detall">Go for Details</a>
   </span>
 <?php 
 if($key == $class_count-1){ // check when classes array values ends start count from 0 again
     $key = 0;
 }else{
    $key++;
 }
}?>
```

**Note:- since `mysql_*` is deprecated now use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Thanks**

Comment: `$class = array('0'=>'A', '1'=>'B')` is not necessary `$class = array('A','B')` will do the same

Comment: (Even better now: `$class = ['A','B']` if your version of PHP is fresh enough)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question, here is what you want to do:

```
<?php
$class=array('A','B','C');
$length = count($class);
$key=0;
while(...) {
  $index = $key % $length;
  $current_class= $class[$index];
  $key += 1;
}
```

$current_class will loop on every class value while $key grows.

$key will take: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc.

but $index will take: 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, etc.

And so $class[$index] will be: 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', etc.

(See "modulus" operator at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can round your array to dynamically use. Here is the example of such things.

**Modified Scripts:**

**Modified Array:**

```
$class = array('pic1-caption bottom-to-top', 
             'pic1-caption top-to-bottom', 
             'pic1-caption left-to-right', 
             'pic1-caption right-to-left', 
             'pic1-caption rotate-in', 
             'pic1-caption rotate-out', 
             'pic1-caption open-up',
             'pic1-caption open-down',
             'pic1-caption open-left',
             'pic1-caption open-right',
             'pic1-caption come-left',
             'pic1-caption come-right');
```

**SQL:**

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from phr_health_care where status=1  order by health_id desc");
```

**Rest of the code:**

```
$len = count($class);
$key = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
<div class="pic1">
    <img src="backend/uploads/<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" class="pic1-image" alt="picture"/>
    <span class="<?php echo $class[$len%$key];?>"> 
        <h1 class="pic1-title">DIABETICS</h1>
        <p class="newp"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></p>
        <a href="health.html" class="detall">Go for Details</a>
    </span>
</div>
<?php 
$key = ($key == ($len-1)) ? 0 : ($key + 1);
}?>
```